# How to change html code in chrome:// pages

Tags: html, google-chrome

How to change the html code in chrome:// pages, for example, a page that has no internet, how do I modify the main code so that even if I enter the page again, the changes remain

Example:

https://images.app.goo.gl/eq5XGEu2f54TWqcf9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, there is no way to change this. a page embedded in an exe

you can use chrome plugins to change the page style.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe